# Как вывести ошибку на стороне клиента в случае неуспешной операции удаления?

Tags: java, mysql, java-ee

Стоит задача по разработке админ панели для интернет-магазина запчастей. Есть таблица товаров и заказов в MySQL, администратор может удалить товар только в том случае, если id товара не используется в базе заказов.

Это все понятно. Удаление сделал, теперь хочу красиво вывести ошибку, если товар есть в заказе, а я его случайно хотел удалить. В сервисном слое try/catch отлавливаю и вывожу надпись ошибки. 
Но хотелось бы реализовать редирект на страничку товаров и вывести ошибку в клиенте.

Не совсем понимаю как это действие реализовать. 
Подскажите пожалуйста. Буду благодарен очень.

Код контроллера по удалению:

```
public class DeleteOrdController implements Controller {
    private OrdService ordService = OrdServiceIpl.getInstance();
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DeleteOrdController.class);

    @Override
    public void execute(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        try{
            String id = req.getParameter("deleteOrd");
            long ordId = Long.parseLong(id);
            ordService.delete(ordId);
            String contextPath = req.getContextPath();
            resp.sendRedirect(contextPath + "/frontController?command=orders");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Таблица товаров:

```
 <table>
        <tr>
            <th>№</th>
            <th>Parts id</th>
            <th>Producer</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Name  parts</th>
            <th>Chatacteristics</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="batteries" items="${parts}" varStatus="status">
            <tr>
                <td>${status.index + 1}</td>
                <td>${batteries.id}</td>
                <td>${batteries.producer}</td>
                <td>${batteries.category}</td>
                <td>${batteries.name}</td>
                <td>${batteries.chatacteristics}</td>
                <td>${batteries.price}</td>
                <td><form action="frontController?command=deleteproduct" method="post">
                    <button value="${batteries.id}" name="delete" class="btn">Delete</button>
                </form></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
    <br/>
```

Сервисный слой:

```
@Override
public int delete(Serializable id) {
    try {
        return partsDao.delete(id);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new ServiceException("Ошибка удаления Parts по id " + id);
    }
}
```

ДАО

```
@Override
public int delete(Serializable id) throws SQLException {
    psDelete.setLong(1, (long) id);
    return psDelete.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Хотелось бы больше информации а то экстрасенсы все в отпуске. Что на UI используете и бэк энде используете? С такой постановкой вопроса можно лиж ответить что там где ловите исключение делайте редирект на страницу.

Comment: Добавил. Пока все примитивно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

т.е. перед удалением товара (parts) нужно проверить его наличие в таблице (orders) 
и если он там имеется, то вывести предупреждение...

Другой вариант, в таблице товаров завести колонку в скольких заказах товар участвует... и например (тут уж от вашей бизнес-логики зависит) каждый новый заказ увеличивает это число на 1, каждый выполненный заказ уменьшает. Если значение больше 0, то удалить товар нельзя.

т.е. и в ДАО и в Сервисе нужны еще специальные методы отвечающие за проверку

Соответсвенно, контроллер получив информацию, о том, что такой товар имеется в заказах, отправляет указание странице вывода, а там под специальным тегом

```
<c:if test = "${canDelete eq false}"> сообщение об ошибке </c:if>
```